# TaxonomyKeywordKeyCriteria ignores publication Id

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, broker, java, query

I'm using `TaxonomyKeywordKeyCriteria` to find Components that have a related Keyword. I only have the Keyword key and not the TCM URI.

My code:

```
Criteria criteria = new TaxonomyKeywordKeyCriteria(taxonomyURI, keyword, true);
Query myQuery = new Query();

PublicationCriteria publicationCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(pubId);
criteria = new AndCriteria(publicationCriteria, criteria);

myQuery.setCriteria(criteria);

String[] itemURIs = null;
itemURIs = myQuery.executeQuery();
```

This code generate the next query:

> 12:16:34,715 DEBUG [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3) SQL: select distinct itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID as col_0_0_, itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID as col_1_0_, itemmeta0_.ITEM_TYPE as col_2_0_, itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID as col_3_0_ from ITEMS itemmeta0_, TAXFACETS taxonomyit1_, TAXFACETS taxonomyit2_, ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS relatedkey3_ where itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and taxonomyit1_.PUBLICATION_ID=itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID and taxonomyit2_.TAXONOMY_ID=taxonomyit1_.TAXONOMY_ID and taxonomyit2_.PUBLICATION_ID=taxonomyit1_.PUBLICATION_ID and itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=relatedkey3_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID and relatedkey3_.KEYWORD_ID=taxonomyit2_.FACET_ID and taxonomyit1_.FACET_KEY=? and taxonomyit1_.TAXONOMY_ID=? and taxonomyit1_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and taxonomyit2_.FACET_LEFT>=taxonomyit1_.FACET_LEFT and taxonomyit2_.FACET_RIGHT<=taxonomyit1_.FACET_RIGHT order by itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID ASC

Then, I published:

- **Publication 1**, Component **A** without related Keyword.
- **Publication 2**, Component **A** with related Keyword **X**.

If I try to find Components that have related the Keyword **X** in Publication 1 is finding the Component **A**, although it doesn't have the Keyword related in this Publication.

Executing the query directly to the database I found that the problem is when is trying to query `ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS` `relatedkey3_`. It isn't using Publication ID.

Could I modify my code to force the use of Publication ID in this case?

Comment: It looks like you're overriding the variable `criteria` which starts out as a `TaxonomyKeywordCriteria` and becomes `AndCriteria`. Theoretically that should be fine, but try using another variable for it and see if there is a difference.

Comment: I checked it without overriding the variable at I have the same results. Thanks.

Comment: Have you published/republished the taxonomy (Category)?

Comment: Yes, I checked the database and all is published correctly. The problem is in the query that generates the api. ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS  isn't limited by pubId and is mixing data from different publications.